# Major edits made to my question about using a string or array to index object in JavaScript

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, closed-questions

I have a question about my post: [Dynamic way to use string/array as index of object in javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184743/dynamic-way-to-use-string-array-as-index-of-object-in-javascript)

I see that my first attempt at this question was outside the scope of what I should ask at Code Review, as the solution I offered was not working for purpose, and what the code needed to do was not clearly explained. I have edited the question a lot, now including a solution that is fit for purpose and explained more clearly what it is needed to do. From reading [help-reopen-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) it seems that after commenting that the question has been improved (which I've done), the next step is to ask a question here? Is there a problem with the question as it currently stands for Code Review?

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for revising the question — Rev 5 is much better as a Code Review question than the original.

That said, I hesitate to reopen it, because I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish with this code.  Why are you calling the function as `change_object_using_path_string("example_object", …)` rather than `change_object_using_path_string(example_object, …)`?  The former basically forces you to use the `eval()`, which you are trying to avoid.

As stated in the [Help Center](/help/on-topic), Code Review requires real code from a project.  Anytime you simplify or obfuscate the code before posting it for review, it creates a bit of uncertainty about what the code is for, and makes it harder to give you solid advice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - A solution that involves inputting example_object directly rather than as string "example_object" would be better, but I haven't worked out a solution that doesn't involve eval to achieve what I want (i.e. change the value at the indexed position of the object with the new value). That's the only reason why I'm inputting the object name as a string. I've edited the question to reflect this.
As for using real code - the function is real, I was trying to use examples for the inputs as the inputs are dynamic.